# Angular Dialog Open problem in component -errors desnt open

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog

I have a problem with Dialog in Angular:
HTML:

```
 <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog(content)">Add</button>

      <template #content>
    Hello Angular!
  </template>
```

TS:

```
   openDialog() {
  this.dialog.open(content);
}
```

Comment: Please share more code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated

Comment: i think you have to bind "content" in your ts. Like that :  @ViewChild('content') content;